# I made an oath months ago but forgot what it was about

Tags: forgiveness, oaths

I took an oath months ago not to do something, I have the general idea but I forgot exactly what I said I wouldn’t do..
Whats one supposed to do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

What you do depends on you only and Allah.
There are many things you can do, thing of it like many plates or cups of tea you can choose to eat or drink from.
Allah sees everything in the past , present and future.He saw it since Hazrat Adam, the first prophet.
If you break the oath, Allah will keep on watching and do as he pleases.

This is not a muslim peer support group so take knowledge and apply it according to what you want and what Allah wants.

Best of Luck.